# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I would like use a FloatingActionButton on my application, I read this : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons#google-s-official-support-library but when I run the Activity I have this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xavier_laffargue.podcast/com.xavier_laffargue.podcast.ACT_Test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

**XML File**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvToDoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/lvToDoList"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Graddle**

```
*apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xavier_laffargue.podcast"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

}
```

Comment: please show full stacktrace

Comment: Do not use MultiDex if you do not have to.

Comment: For others who come across this, also make sure that your support library matches the compile target SDK that you are using within your app.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Please change it into AppCompatActivity if you use Activity. Probably it becomes the error when it is Activity.

Comment: Thanks @Mizuki Sonoko

Comment: aftre changing this i got new error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

Comment: changing the layout to androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout fixes it for me

Comment: thanks @JessonAtherton - I had switched to AndroidX and forgotten about it

Answer (score 48):

For those using **`AndroidX`** Dependency

Along with changing dependencies, **`XML`** must also be changed.

**from**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

**to**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

Answer (score 26):

Just use this line in FloatingActionButton (`app` instead of `android`):

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

Answer (score 18):

Please put `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'` inside your project build.gradle file

Comment: This is the logical answer !

Comment: I believe this is the most often missed issue as it doesn't appear in most other answers nor examples.   The answer above mentions both appcompat and design, so is technically more correct, but I bet most people wouldn't get this far if appcompat were missing.  The actual version of design doesn't matter, so feel free to use a newer one if your Android Studio has a newer one already installed.

Comment: now google play say it must be 28 min, and it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error. Just change the project parent theme to

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

or any other Theme.AppCompat*

Answer (score 6):

You have to include the support libraries.

1. Go to "Project Structure" -> Dependencies
2. On the right side click "+" and select "1. Library dependency"
3. Search for "android.support"
4. Add both:

   - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:.......
   - com.android.support:design:........
5. Sync Gradle
   [image]
   Happy codding! :)

Answer (score 4):

needed both:

- extend AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  ```
- parent of used style (/res/values/styles.xml)

  ```
  <style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  ```

additionally:

- define colors in styles.xml

  ```
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  ```

Comment: and to complete the answer, define color.xml as something like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>

    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>

    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

</resources>

Comment: In my particular case, even after implementing all these steps, I had to instantiate CoordinatorLayout on the XML file using its extended name:

`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
...>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

Comment: I did all these steps and it still won't work for me. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

Add these dependencies into your gradle file. This may solve the problem in some cases.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## For Xamarin Developers:

*(supports Android API 7 to 22+)*

1. Make sure you have installed following components:

   - Android Support Design Library
   - Android Support Library v7 AppCompat
2. Make sure all NuGet packages for these components are installed and referenced. These are:

   - Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
   - Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
   - Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
   - Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView
3. Your Apps Activity should derive from `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity`
4. Your used style has to be derived from a `Theme.AppCompat.*` style. So your `Resources\values\styles.xml` should look like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#AB000D</item>
           <item name="colorPrimary">#E53935</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">#00B8D4</item>
       </style>
       <!-- other styles... -->
   </resources>
   ```
5. Also make sure you actually use the theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

   ```
   <application android:theme="@style/YourAppTheme"></application>
   ```

Comment: Where should I put the number 4?

Comment: Updated the answer. File is found in your resources, if not create one: `Resources\values\styles.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in your app's build gradle the following support library.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

that was last year, now the latest version is

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I came across this error when using a mix of **`androidx`** and `android.support.v7` libraries.

See my solution for that version of this error here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490825/1762493

Answer (score 0):

For those using AndroidX Dependency.
 In your   xml files make sure all your

```
 android.support.???
```

nodes inside CoordinatorLayout's
(like included ActionBars) 
are also replaced with

```
androidx.??? (or com.google.android.???)
```

ones .

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me

Disable Instant Run

File => Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Instant Run