# No such method Error Floating action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button, nosuchmethoderror

Installed Project on another computer. Now i get an "no such method error" because of a floating action button which causes the Activity to crash. I tried several things (mostly updating dependencies and so on) but nothing helps.

Anyone faced this issue or knows how to fix it?

Here is the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                                                                               at MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:230)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                               at MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:230) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.<init>
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                               at onCreate(MapsActivity.java:230) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

gradle-file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", "AIzaSyDvYeaYsC6HzIcj2aYwhsq4FoKQ6N4I1tw"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", "AIzaSyBqbhPyN2c60ViYQAD219jBMt1TkwzNxWE"
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and manifest:

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />

<!-- GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- if you want to keep processor from sleeping when a message is received -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />



<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1496945817221747"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DiscoverActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_discover"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ProfileActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- FACEBOOK ACTIVITY -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FriendsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friends"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <!-- GCM -->


    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--receiver
        android:name=".ExternalReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />

            <category android:name=".androidtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver-->

    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--service
        android:name=".MyGcmRegistrationService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service-->

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <!-- make API to register app to GCM available -->
    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".LoadImageService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".AddFriendService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".AcceptFriendService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".JoinService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".DeleteService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <!--service
        android:name=".MessageReceivingService"
        android:label=".MessageReceivingService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".AndroidMobilePushApp" />
            <action android:name=".ExternalReceiver" />

            <category android:name=".androidtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service-->

    <activity
        android:name=".BasesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bases"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Floating action button:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_locate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/icn_target"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorStorowBlue"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: try these suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571097/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout

Comment: post your manifest's code where you are adding dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Would comment but not enough rep.

Check this out:
[InflateException with FloatingActionButton from Official Design Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870443/inflateexception-with-floatingactionbutton-from-official-design-library)

Look at your theme and compat libraries.