# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

why when I run my project I get this error? It is the first time that I have this kind of issue! So I hope that you can help me!

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`:`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

This is the code:

GRADLE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
//    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.navigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

}
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace - the answer is likely in one of those "Caused by" nested exceptions.

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity . Post your code and style.xml instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571097/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: @ADM https://pastebin.com/jd6Br8qk

Comment: Put your activity's style in question from style.xml

Comment: @ADM https://pastebin.com/xECTEjuN

Comment: At first its looks like a Style error. Post the full stacktrace . Do not add links in comment while you can edit your question .

Comment: @ADM can i post you link project? so you can downloaded it and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `CoordinatorLayout` [is added in version 24.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html). So, you need to update your support library design to version `24.1.0`. You're better to use the latest stable of support library, which is `26.1.0` (there is version 27, but the API status is still in preview mode).